# How is bagging different from cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, model-evaluation, bagging

How is bagging different from cross-validation? Can a data set having 300 examples can be 100 bagged and would it be helpful at all?

Answer (score 10):

To add to @juampa's answer,

The big difference between bagging and validation techniques is that bagging averages models (or predictions of an ensemble of models) in order to reduce the variance the prediction is subject to while resampling validation such as cross validation and out-of-bootstrap validation evaluate a number of surrogate models assuming that they are equivalent (i.e. a good surrogate) for the actual model in question which is trained on the whole data set.

Bagging uses bootstrapped subsets (i.e. drawing with replacement of the original data set) of training data to generate such an ensemble but you can also use ensembles that are produced by drawing without replacement, i.e. cross validation: [Beleites, C. & Salzer, R.: Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations, Anal Bioanal Chem, 390, 1261-1271 (2008). DOI: 10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6)

Whether an ensemble model can be better than single models depends entirely on what the dominant "problem" of the single model is. If it is variance (overfitting, random error, unstable predictions), then ensemble prediction can help. If the problem is bias (systematic error, underfitting, stable but wrong predictions), pretty much all models of the ensemble will give the same prediction and the ensemble prediction is just as wrong.

Both out-of-bootstrap and iterated/repeated cross validation allow to measure the stability of predictions by comparing predictions for *the same* input (test) data by a number of different surrogate models. These surrogate models differ in that they were trained on slightly different data sets, that can be described as exchanging a few training cases between any two of the surrogate models for other training cases.

---

As for the assumption of independence @juampa mentions, there are different topics behind this:

- All these techniques typically assume that the splitting of the data achieves independence between the cases. I.e. if there are repeated measurements of the same case in the data, they are all in or all out of a particular training or test set.
  This is a crucial assumption that allows us to assume the observed performance generalizes to unknown cases of the same population the data comes from. It is typically up to you to ensure the splitting is done in a way that achieves this independence of cases: without intimate knowledge about the data it is not possible to make sure of such an independent splitting.
  Such a splitting into independent cases is needed both by resampling validation and ensemble models if they are to be useful for predicting independent cases.
- There is another independence assumption that is *sometimes* but not always made for validation results (or rather, during their interpretation):

  - For some tasks such as the general comparison of algorithms, the surrogate models in a resampling validation are sometimes treated as if they were independent trials of the algorithm. Which is quite obviously not the case, as the models share most of their training data (with the exception of a single 2-fold split).
    This assumption is needed in order to generalize the findings on *this* data set to *a* data set of the given characteristics.
  - On the other hand, if the task is to establish the performance of *the* model obtained from *the* data set at hand (which is e.g. actually to be used for prediction), then the surrogate models are assumed to be equivalent, if not perfectly to *the* model in question (the well-known slight pessimistic bias of resampling validation) then at least among themselves. This point of view means that the training data of the different surrogate models are *not* assumed to be independent but quite the opposite: they are assumed to be almost equal (which is what the resampling process actually produces).

Answer (score 3):

[Bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) is useful when you work with classifiers that can achieve high accuracy because they tend to overfit (for example decision trees and neural networks) but because of that, show high variance, specially in the small data domain. Then you generate bootstraps samples of your data, train classifiers on each of them, and then use the aggregate to classify so that you can average out errors due to overfitting.

[Cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is about evaluating how well your model does, but you have limited data. Again, you have the problem that your estimate might not be robust enough.

Both share the problem that when used, one makes the assumption that the estimates for each iteration (the classifier that results from each bootstrap iteration and the error of the classifier resulting from each cross-validation step, resp.) are statistically independent. Which is not true. See for example [A Study of CrossValidation and Bootstrap for Accuracy Estimation and Model Selection](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~ronnyk/accEst.pdf) and [Bagging Predictors](https://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/421.pdf) for further details.

So yes, they might be helpful in your case.

Comment: The assumption of independence which is is not met is only made for particular types of use of the validation results. Namely, for generalizing the results of the one data set at hand to *a* data set of similar characteristics. Another typical use, estimating performance for *the* model built from the data at hand makes the opposite assumption: it assumes no (important) difference between the models. Please see my answer for a more detailed explanation.